# Jupyter Notebook recursion limit vs windows console

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I had a function that triggered a recursion error when I ran it in my windows command line, but not in jupyter notebook. I did some Googling and found `sys.getrecursionlimit()` and the default python limit is 1000, but the default jupyter notebook value is 3000. I read that setting the recursion limit higher can crash the program and is not advised. So my question is why is the default 3 times higher in jupyter? Is it really that dangerous to raise the limit to much higher values?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do simple mistakes with recursion and cause infinite loop, utilising 100% of CPU core. Recursion limit prevents that and exits program. You can set it higher if you need to.

Note that by setting it to 10000 it'll take 10x longer to exit unintended infinite loop. Sometimes the function involves creating new files and 1000 is just a safe value.